# How to check diskspace in java 5

Tags: java

I have written a java program to calculate diskspace and send mail when it is less than a particular threshhold value. I need to run it on a machine which has java5 which does not have any menthods like getTotalSpace(), getFreeSpace() in java6, how can we calculate the diskpace in any prior version.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju The answers there say Java 6 all over the place.

Comment: I think the serious answer is: dump that machine. Seriously: you don't write cobol programs anymore by pushing holes into punchcards. You also don't use Java5 any more in 2017. In other words: get rid of that dependency. Anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: @GhostCat - Read the accepted answer.  The stuff below the horizontal line .....